# How to download multiple files from database in a zip format? When you do not have name of the files

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have files stored in database. I do not have name stored in the database so i am checking the first 4 bytes of byte array to find out if the file is pdf or jpg.. at present i am able to download only one file at a time. I want to download all the files that are in the DataTable in a zip format.. (since i do not have the original name of the files i am wiling to give it a random name WITH the extension i get after comparison)

```
DataRow objRow;
objAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
SqlCommandBuilder sqlCmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(objAdapter);
objAdapter.Fill(objTable);
objRow = objTable.Rows[1];
byte[] objData;
objData = (byte[])objRow["img"];
// Stream stream = new MemoryStream(objData);
var firstNBytes = objData.Take(4);
Byte[] threeBytes = new Byte[] { objData[0], objData[1], objData[2], objData[3] };
var bytesToCompare = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("0x25");
bool equal = firstNBytes.SequenceEqual(bytesToCompare);
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(threeBytes);
hex.Replace("-", "");

if (objSfd.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.Cancel)
{
string strFileToSave = objSfd.FileName;

//string strFileToSave = "abc";

if (hex == "25-50-44-46")
{
    strFileToSave += ".pdf";
}
else
{
    strFileToSave += ".jpg";
}

FileStream objFileStream = new FileStream(strFileToSave, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
objFileStream.Write(objData, 0, objData.Length);
objFileStream.Close();
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Perhaps you need a Zip library to help you. Look at http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/ or http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/Default.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> at present i am able to download only one file at a time. I want to
>   download all the files that are in the DataTable in a zip format.

Try iterating through your **objTable.Rows** like this,

```
objAdapter.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
SqlCommandBuilder sqlCmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(objAdapter);
objAdapter.Fill(objTable);
foreach(DataRow objRow in objTable.Rows)
{
byte[] objData = (byte[])objRow["img"];
var firstNBytes = objData.Take(4);
Byte[] threeBytes = new Byte[] { objData[0], objData[1], objData[2], objData[3] };
var bytesToCompare = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes("0x25");
bool equal = firstNBytes.SequenceEqual(bytesToCompare);
string hex = BitConverter.ToString(threeBytes);
hex.Replace("-", "");


string strFileToSave = Guid.NewGuid();

if (hex == "25-50-44-46")
{
    strFileToSave += ".pdf";
}
else
{
    strFileToSave += ".jpg";
}

FileStream objFileStream = new FileStream(strFileToSave, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
objFileStream.Write(objData, 0, objData.Length);
objFileStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: I already did that... but instead of downloading one by one it would be much better to download all attachments in one go.

Comment: what do you mean by download all attachment in one go? @Arbaaz

Comment: If you already did that why do you post question like that?@Arbaaz

Comment: Sorry i did not read your post well.. I had not tried that BUT now that i have .. its not downloading anything.. probably because `strFileToSave` in your code has only the GUID and not the local system path where files will be downloaded

Comment: Check your projects output directory where your exe are located. all the files must be there. @Arbaaz

Comment: Yup! You are right they are in my bin directory... but can we not specify a default path where they will be stored? Like giving user option to store it on desktop or anywhere else?

Comment: of curse you can. Just create a folder manually or programatically and change the string strFileToSave = Guid.NewGuid(); to string strFileToSave = "C:\\Your Folder Name\\"+Guid.NewGuid();